# При использовании свойства FormBorderStyle в значении None пропала иконка в панели задач

Tags: c#, winforms

Я использовал это свойство (помечено синим на скриншоте), и у меня пропала иконка приложения (помечено красным на скриншоте, где она должна быть). Как поставить иконку на место?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема не воспроизводится, убедитесь, что у вас установлено свойство `ShowInTaskbar` в `True`

Comment: Аналогично, не смог воспроизвести. MSVS2012, MonoDevelop. Как в отладке, так и в релизе - всё нормально отображается. ЧЯДН? Ссылка на тестовый проект: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QVPyi41hiKWHO7n3jux5twApX9rbD0iX

Comment: У меня закралось подозрение, что вы самостоятельно меняете флаги отображения формы через WinAPI. Проясните, так ли это?

Comment: @test123 Запустил ваш проект, тоже самое что и у меня. Я думаю это из-за того что я работаю в MVS 2017.

Comment: @Владимир, 2017... Я так понимаю, и ОС у вас другая, у меня win7. Возможно, что то поменялось в поведении самой ОС.

Comment: @test123, то есть выходит, что других методов как я уже писал скрытия стандартной Windows-обёртки окна нет?

Answer (score -1):

Никак, свойство None убирает иконку, так же как и FixedDialog, если вы ставите это свойство что бы запретить менять размер формы, установите свойство MaximumSize и MinimumSize равным свойству Size.

Comment: Тогда может есть альтернативный метод скрытия стандартной Windows-обёртки окна?

Comment: Скорее всего только через костыли) Например сделать другую форму главной, у нее в начале класса надо дописать this.Opacity = 0;
И потом открывать вашу форму без обертки, тем самым,  Главная форма будет прозрачной, и будет выступать в роли и конки.
P.S Возможно есть более Адекватный способ решения вашей проблемы)

Comment: >>None убирает иконку<< Чем тестировали?

Comment: Точно, моя вина. Но я почему-то был уверен что так и есть...